# Uisng Http_mock_adpter on integration testing is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-integration-test

I have been trying to use flutter integration testing. now the code has api calls at several place, so I have modified in a way that a single dio client will be used for api calls, throughout the application as below.

```
class AppSession extends GetxController {
   final Dio dio;
   AppSession(this.dio); 
   //other methods and properties
}
// and this is my main.dart file contents, 
        
AppSession get currentSession => Get.find<AppSession>();
void main() async {
  Get.lazyPut(() => AppSession(Dio()));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

So everywhere in the file when i need a client, I'll call "currentSession.dio". Now I'm writing the integration testing for a login page as below. These are the contents of main.dart in integration_test.

```
IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final dio = Dio();
  setUp(() {
    Get.reset();
    // Set up Dio with the adapter
    Dio adjustedDio = setAdapter(dio);
    // Provide the adjusted Dio instance to the AppSession
    Get.lazyPut(() => AppSession(adjustedDio));
  });
  group('end-to-end test', () {
    testWidgets('login with email and password test', (tester) async {
    // Load app widget.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
    // other testing code...
    Finder loginButton = find.text("LOGIN");
    await tester.tap(loginButton);
    // other testing code...
});
```

});

and I'm using "chromedriver" to test the application. "setAdapter(dio)", it takes the client and binds the "DioAdapter" from the "http_mock_adapter". Here i configured the hard-coded http requests and their corresponding responses

when the tester taps the login button, nothing happens and the tests are failed. The application is working fine on actual APIs but I could not write tests for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your original dio instance. Just add an adapter for it:

```
final dio = Dio();
final dioAdapter = DioAdapter(dio: dio));
```

Then you have to mock responses:

```
  dioAdapter.onPost(
    '/auth/login',
    data: {
      "primary_email": 'user1@email.com',
      "password": '123123123',
    },
    (server) => server.reply(
      200,
      mockResponse,
      // Reply would wait for one-sec before returning data.
      delay: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    ),
  );
```

And then just use your **dio**.